What is a simple example of transforming some Objects / Arrows in visual, categorical definition into actual Coq code. An MWE recipe that is
Injective object - Wikipedia
In modern category theory literature, the whole definition of injective object can be written as:
Definition. An object $Q$ in a category $C$ is injective $\iff$:

commutes.
Question.

I'm wondering what is the MWE to write this definition in Coq, given that the user (of some hypothetical diagramming app) specifies the diagram + the lhs text of the $\iff$ + "commutes".

Ideally I would like to see a technique that is easily adapted to handle other such single-diagram rules (theorems or definitions).
To read the diagram, anything that isn't dotted is $\forall$ prefixed internally (implicitly, so you don't see the $\forall$) and a dotted line means $\exists$.  If an object is needing to be an $\exists$ instead of a $\forall$ prefixed name, then you'd prefix it explicitly with $\exists$.  Split tail arrow of course means monomorphism.

There are a few Coq category theory libraries but none of them seem to have projective or injective objects. I would recommend looking at Agda libraries instead: agda-categories has injective morphisms, which you can use to define injective objects.

@NaïmFavier why can't it be defined easily enough? I would like the easiest to use Proof assistant, but I thought that was Coq...

@NaïmFavier looking at that Agda code it's not a direct translation of the above diagram because they've defined a utility Lift function.  Is such a thing necessary?

You haven't defined what a "direct translation" is. I think it's a pretty direct translation; you can of course inline Lifts and Filler (as a $\Sigma$-type) if you like.

@NaïmFavier what about my first question?  Why is this simple definition difficult in Lean4 / Coq or did I interpret what you said incorrectly?

I don't expect it to be difficult in any modern proof assistant.

As a tangent, I remember someone (Freyd?) coming up with a uniform system of symbols representing nested quantifiers with diagrams. Does anyone remember who?

The diagram is not a valid definition of injective objects. There has to be some accompanying information about the things appearing in it (how they're quantified, for example). In any case, it's easy to formalize a notion such as injectivity, even if it isn't yet in the library.

@Trebor are you thinking of Frege's notation in Begriffsschrift?

It’s the diagram + the text surrounding it + ability to expand definitions recursively which defines the injective object for the user.   By expand I probably mean go to with a link

Feel free to answer with either Coq or Lean4.   I’m looking for a way to consistently translate these text + diagram snippets.   It doesn’t have to be perfect either, but that would be nice

Also note that and this makes it 100x easier is the translation I’m after is a one way street so we don’t have to worry about converting Lean4 to this form.

Lean already has injective objects in its mathlib: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/CategoryTheory/Preadditive/Injective.html

I guess for things already defined we’ll have option to create in user’s personal space or link to the built-in definition .

Since in the comments you say Lean is ok, here is the definition of CategoryTheory.Injective in Mathlib.  (I found it with Moogle.ai.)
variable {C : Type u₁} [Category.{v₁} C]

/--
An object `J` is injective iff every morphism into `J` can be obtained by extending a monomorphism.
-/
class Injective (J : C) : Prop where
  factors : ∀ {X Y : C} (g : X ⟶ J) (f : X ⟶ Y) [Mono f], ∃ h : Y ⟶ J, f ≫ h = g

Follow the above documentation link to explore the definitions/notations of category (Category), morphism (⟶), monomorphism (Mono), and composition (≫) used in the definition.
It is defined as a type class (in Prop) wrapping the forall-exist property you mention.  Notice Category, Mono, and (this definition) Injective are type classes.  I’m not sure if you are familiar with type classes in Lean, but they are heavily used in the MathLib category theory library. They let you work with the normal presentations of an object, but apply theorems about, in this case, injective objects as long as Lean’s type class system knows your object is an instance of the Injective type class.
